# Refresh gridview inside updatepanel after data available

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I would like to display asp.NET page which contains 4 update panels and data refresh on button click and for the firsttime. My questions are below

1. How to Load page content first and then data? I do not want to keep my dataload methods in page load
2. Is there anyway to refresh the page/updatepanel from code behind ( I did call __dopostback event or javascript from code behind.. it did not work)

Thanks for your help

```
           <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1"   UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
       <ContentTemplate>
                        <button id="btnCrashRefresh" onserverclick="btnCrashRefresh_ServerClick" type="submit" runat="server" class="btn btn-default pull-right" style="padding-top: 0px;padding-bottom: 0px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" ></span></button>

                            <asp:Label ID="Label1"  class=" label-info pull-right" runat="server" Text="<Date time>" ></asp:Label>
                  </ContentTemplate>            
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code Behind

```
 System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (! Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        SetInitialValues();

        btnCrashRefresh.ServerClick += new EventHandler(btnCrashRefresh_ServerClick);

        myTimer.Interval = 2000;
        myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(myTimer_Elapsed);
        myTimer.Start();


    }
}

void myTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

       string script = "DoPostback();";

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(btnCrashRefresh, this.GetType(), "Refresh", getjQueryCode(script), true);



    }
```

Javascript

```
function DoPostback() {
             __doPostBack('<%=btnCrashRefresh %>');

         }
```

Comment: Nice questions... where's the code to judge/help/guide?

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm more of a VB.NET developer:

1- Pages in ASP.NET have a lifecycle, and yes, you are right, it is not really a good Idea to use on LOAD. Here is a brief description of the page life cycle [ASP.NET Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.85).aspx) , and the best part where you can bind all data to your panels is in the PreRender

2- Is this on a button Click? If so, you pretty much need something like this:

```
 Public Sub btnRefresh_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRefresh.Click
    updatePanel1.Update()
    updatePanel2.Update()
    updatePanel3.Update()
    updatePanel4.Update()
End Sub
```

Here is the C# Vers:

```
public void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    updatePanel1.Update();
    updatePanel2.Update();
    updatePanel3.Update();
    updatePanel4.Update();
}
```

I hope this answers what you need :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Timer control in AJAX to refresh your data periodically. 
For that add a timer control. Set its interval in milliseconds and generate its tick event handler method and also  create a function to load you data into the controls like this:

```
private void LoadData()
{
   //Load you data here
}
```

and call this `LoadData` method in `pageload` method if **Not** `IsPostBack` and in

timer's tick event.

Comment: This sounds good... but I do not want to load this reload the page on timer tick, I will keep buttons to refresh partial page on demand.  please let me know is there any possibility to stop timer

Comment: So why were you having a system timer in the first place in your code if you didn't want periodic refresh? Please Enlighten me with what exactly is your requirement.

Comment: I given timer to show the page first and then call method and pull the data; later stop timer not to re occur

Comment: Okay. In that case you can disable the timer. use `Timer.Enabled=false`

Comment: Which timer did you disable? You have to disable the Ajax timer